# Bundling app for app store distribution in Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I can't believe how difficult it is to figure out the final process for building an app and getting it into the app store.

I've already prepped iTunes Connect with my app and it shows up in Application Loader.

I finally figured out how to "archive" the app, although none of the guides I found, including Apple's, seemed to really describe this process in complete detail.

Now I've got a .xcarchive package. For some reason, Application Loader will not let me select that kind of file. I read somewhere about needing to archive as a .zip file, so I tried that. Now Application Loader allows me to select the file, but after I click Send, it gives me this error:

"The application wrapper must end in .app."

What **exactly** is the process of archiving from Xcode 4.3 and getting the application uploaded into the app store?

Comment: you can extract your app to .ipa file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XCode Organizer, does the 'Archives' tab allow ou to 'Distribute'?  You should then have the option to 'Submit to the iOS App Store'.

This is described in more detail in [Distributing Your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/distributing_ios_apps.html).

The submission process doesn't get a lot of description because, when it works, it's quite simple.  You never need to manually locate the '.xcarchive' package or '.ipa' file for your app store submission, only for testing or backups outside the app store.  (You do need the archive package, but it's just quietly created and then uploaded by XCode.)

Comment: Strange, I looked in that area several times after archiving and it was always empty. This morning I see my build from last night. Just to test it again, I did another archive. It did not show up in there. I restarted Xcode and still didn't see it. I then set xcode aside for a minute, went back to the Archives tab, and there it was. Very strange! Thanks!